# Selenium driver's method 'driver.set_page_load_time(30)' error

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, page-load-time

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
```

I'm trying to use the selenium driver to crawl data from the web. However, when setting the max loading time for each page in python, I always get the error and tell me nothing useful. I am using Mac and python version is 2.7. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? It really drives me crazy.

[image]

Comment: At the bottom of that image... `WebDriverException: Message:`. Does it say anything below that? Also, if you can post the error directly in the question, that helps prevent the image link going stale and makes it so networks that block image sharing(like mine) can still see the error. I had to look up the question on my phone to see it. Cheers :)

Comment: Sorry about the image and I'll change it next time...Sadly, there is nothing left below the ''WebDriverException: Message:" ,so the exception tells me nothing useful to fix the problem, I doubt that it's  selenium' bug to print the empty message.

Comment: Yikes yeah that's not a helpful message, the best I can suggest is try updating your geckodriver for firefox if you haven't already done that, it could be that your current ff version isn't supported with the driver you're using.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the geckodriver and the error is gone! I read the geckodriver document carefully and found that the geckodriver must  match with the selenium and firefox precisely as the geckodriver 0.15.0 added the timeout method(you can read the geckodriver document in https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). My selenium version is 3.3.1 and geckodriver version is 0.15 with the  firefox 53.0. I also found the similar problem with same solution in selenium's official bug tracker(https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3661). I put it here for anyone with the same problem.

Comment: Glad that worked out, otherwise it would have been awful to track down what that error message meant :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is a result of `geckodriver`, `firefox`, and `selenium` not being on a version that supported eachother.

The solution is to update `geckodriver`.

Additional resources OP posted in comments for reference:
github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
Similar problem with same solution